# How to get jQuery added values in aspx page at server side on Submit button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

When user clicks 'add new' button I want to add more textbox into the page, so that he can add n number of values. I will do this with jQuery. But on submit click I want to get values from all the fields at server side. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: you cant!! you need to call via ajax.

Comment: This StackOverflow Question gave answer


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437955/submitting-form-elements-with-the-same-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store values in hidden field which has runat="server" using javascript and use that hidden field in server side code of asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuery.clone()` to make a clone of the inputbox.

Remember this inputbox will be in array form as below

```
<input name="clonedbox[]"
```

and then just send it in `submit` function or `ajax` call.